# Visual C++: Unable to invoke method from another class

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, c++-cli

Please have a look at the following code

**Form1.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Clicker.h"

namespace TestWindowProject {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(115, 91);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                 Clicker c;
                 c.click();
             }
    };
}
```

**Clicker.h**

```
#pragma once
ref class Clicker
{
public:
    Clicker(void);
    void click();
};
```

Clicker.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Clicker.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Clicker::Clicker(void)
{
}

void Clicker::click()
{
    cout << "Clicked" << endl;
}
```

This is my first GUI application in C++. When I click the button, nothing is happening! I can't see anything in the output! Why is that? Am I doing something wrong? please help

Comment: I added the C++/CLI and WinForms tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program seems to be a WinForms C++/CLI GUI application. So, if you want to show some output, instead of using `cout` (which is fine for C++ console apps, not for GUI-based WinForms apps), you could use something like [`MessageBox::Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/519bytz3.aspx):

```
//
// Instead of : 
//
//    cout << "Clicked" << endl;
//
MessageBox::Show( L"Clicked" );
```

Comment: Yep, it worked. Anyway, why this Visual Studio Intellisense is not working?

Comment: In VS2010, IntelliSense [doesn't support C++/CLI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/03/10136696.aspx). You have to use [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) for that purpose.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Since that is not free, I guess I am gonna have a hard time with GUI. Sad story is, I have submitted my university real time software report saying I will do in C++! I could have go with JAVA!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Yohan: I don't have VS2012 Express, but [C++/CLI IntelliSense was made available in VS2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh409293.aspx), so you may want to try the Express download.