# How do I create a C++/CLI Winforms app in VS2012?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, user-interface, c++-cli

I just installed Visual Studio 2012 express for Desktop. I can't see any place to create a GUI application with C++ ! Where is this "Windows Form Application" used to exists in Visual C++ 2010 ? Where are these drag and drop controls? I installed this because I got details telling this supports GUI intellisense ([Visual C++: Unable to invoke method from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177179/visual-c-unable-to-invoke-method-from-another-class))

Comment: @chris: :O :O ... OK, but where is this?

Comment: I'm not sure about the GUI builder, but it will probably work hardcoded with a CLR project.

Comment: [This looks promising.](http://www.abouthack.com/articles/programming/c-plus-plus/windows-forms-application-in-visual-c-2012.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is an unsubtle hint that they want you to stop creating C++/CLI Winforms applications.  The plumbing is still in place however, at least for VS2012 and VS2013.  This might not be the case in a future one.

You can turn a CLR console application into a Winforms application with these steps:

- Start with File + New + Project, CLR node, CLR Console Application
- Project + Add New Item, UI node, Windows Form
- Project + Properties, Linker, System, SubSystem = Windows
- Project + Properties, Linker, Advanced, Entry Point = main

Change the pre-generated .cpp file to look like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyForm.h"

namespace ConsoleApplication45 {    // Change this!!
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

    [STAThread]
    int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
    {
        Application::EnableVisualStyles();
        Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
        Application::Run(gcnew MyForm());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note that you'll need to change the namespace name to your project name.  Press F5 to test.  You can design the form as normal once everything checks out.

---

NOTE, Visual Studio 2015 has a nasty static initialization order bug in the CRT that can cause the app to crash instantly with an AVE at startup if the project contains any native C++ code.  As yet an unfixed bug, the somewhat inevitable hazard of having these project templates removed.  [A possible workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41485935/17034) is to change the Entry Point (4th bullet).

For a project that targets x86, copy paste this string:

```
?mainCRTStartupStrArray@@$$FYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z
```

For a project that targets x64, copy paste:

```
?mainCRTStartupStrArray@@$$FYMHP$01EAPE$AAVString@System@@@Z
```

---

Somewhere around VS2017 the designer fails to open a new form with a cryptic error message.  Workaround is to build the project first, use Build > Build.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going to give up C++/CLI :(

Comment: @ Hans Passant Do they want you to create Windows Store apps instead?

Comment: @Hans Passant, can we get more information on this? What is Microsofts alternative for C++ if they are trying to phase it out?

Comment: You ought to ask Microsoft.  Their only obvious intentions for C++ are MFC and WinRT, the vast majority of programmers use languages like C# or Javascript to create a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the #include "stdafx.h" and this works well for VS 2022. The form must be hand coded since the Form Designer support was removed starting with VS 2012.