# How To Create a New Windows Forms Application Project in Visual C++ 2013 Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

The project template to make a Windows Forms App is missing in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.
This is working for real. I it found online. It was in Spanish by someone. So I re-wrote it in English. Please see my answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the C++ GUI Builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188757/where-is-the-c-gui-builder)

Comment: I was looking for a duplicate before writing this. I was not able to find the duplicate. Anyway, the way I put my question is better.

Answer (score 2):

The following are the steps to make such a project:

1. Go in the menu bar: File => New => Project, to get a list of project templates.
2. Select in the tree to the left go: Templates => Visual C++. Select on the right of the of the window of the templates list : Empty Project (Visual C++) .
3. There will be in the "Solution Explorer" a new tree of files which belong to your new project. Expand it. Let's say you got a new project named "Project1". You'll get on the top of the tree "Solution Project1 (1 project)" . After expanding the tree, You should get on the top of the expansion something called "Project1" right under "Solution Project1 (1 project)" . Right-click "Project1". Select "Add New Item" from the right-click menu.
4. In "Add New Item" from, in the tree to the left , go : Visual C++ => UI => Windows Forms. click save.
   You'll get the question "You are adding a CLR component to a native project. The project will be converted to have Common Language Runtime support. Do you want to continue?" . Click "Yes" .
   Again, one more time, right-click "Project1" and go "Properties".
5. On the tree to left, go : Configuration Properties => Linker => System. And to the right of the properties window set "SubSystem" as "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)" .
6. Also go: Configuration Properties => Linker => Advanced . And to the right of the properties window, set "Entry Point" to "main". If you cannot not see "Entry Point", just re-open the properties window again. This is the function "main" given below. this is where you're application will start running from.
7. Finally, Double-click the form designer and move the cursor to the bottom of the code just right before the closing brace of "namespace Project1". Paste the following code. Please remember to rename the variables of this code according to your project needs to get it working with the empty form.

   ```
   [STAThread]
   void main(array<String^>^ arg) {
       Application::EnableVisualStyles();
       Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

       MyForm form;
       Application::Run(%form);
   }
   ```

Credit for this answer goes to @superlinux.

Answer (score 1):

The guide did not work for me so I searched in YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AP8Tz9RfbxE) and its easy to put following code in `MyForm.cpp` instead of the code that the post had given and it works.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]

void main(array<String^>^ args)
{

    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Project1::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be late, but other users may be curious on how to do this while keeping the terminal window open. This way you can test minor stuff by using `cout`. Anyways, instead of placing the `int main()` in the UI, you can make another .cpp file (just the cpp not a whole new class) and in it you would have something like:

```
#include "MainWindow.h" //which is the name of the UI file
using namespace Projectname //you can check this at the top of the UI file says something like namespace Projectname { ui code }

[STATHREADATTRIBUTE] //you need this otherwise your window can't run things like the webbrowser
int main(){
    MainWindow mw; //the name of the header file
    mw.ShowDialog(); //this brings up the window, you can use mw.Hide() to close it
    return 0; 
}
```

This way you dont really have to mess with the configurations and can keep the terminal window open. I believe you can turn the terminal window off through the config properties later. But I usually prefer this way because its easier to test my code.