# Visual Studio 2013 Express - Resource Editing Not Available

Tags: c++

So I have VS 2013 Express - Desktop and I cannot edit or even view resources for C++! I need to use dialogs, and be able to edit the mainframe and do things with the resource view but it is not there. Does anybody know if there is an extension I could add to VS to get this??

Thanks,

Comment: Just FYI: the [link in that dupe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs24szh9.aspx) shows that the resource editor should be available in "Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop". You should find out [how to create and edit resources in VS2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxb70x7.aspx).

Comment: VS 2013 does not give me the option to add/edit/view resources. The menu is not there. The MSND help files would be useful if I had the menus they are referring to....

Comment: OK, my bad closing your question then. The documentation is incorrect or some other thing is going on. Are you working on a "Win32 Windows Application" or something else? Your question has almost no information to help us help you at the moment.

Comment: Its all good. I just don't understand why the resource menu is not there. I did not get the option to disable it in the install process. But hopefully I will get something figured out. Thank you for your help anyways.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the question you posted in your last comment. I am working with "Win32 Project." Do you think maybe there is a template I don't have that does have the resource stuff? The only two options in my New Project wizard are win32 console and win32 project.

Comment: No... I checked with a fresh install of VS2013 Express for Desktop and also cannot find anything resource file related. I think the documentation is just wrong, and you're out of luck, but maybe someone can shed some light on this...

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Express editions do not support the Visual Studio plug-in architecture.  C# in Visual Studio Express supports WPF and Windows Forms development.

Another alternative is to use WxSmith or QtCreator with Visual C++ as the compiler.

Visual GUI development for C++/CLI + Windows Forms (i.e. .Net) was directly supported in VC++ 2010 Express still available [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_4).  It can still be done in VS2013 but is somewhat "hidden" by not having a project wizard/template, the method is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188757/where-is-the-c-gui-builder).

Express editions have never supported Native Win32 visual GUI development - the idea is to encourage .Net development, and for that you are better off using C# to be totally honest.

Comment: Are those stand alone applications or plug ins to VS?

Comment: QtCreator is stand-alone, WxSmith is a plug-in for Code::Blocks.  There is a Qt Plugin for VS, but as I said Express does not support plugins.  Qt Creator can however use the VC++ compiler from Express (so you have to install both).  Code::Blocks is on Windows is commonly used with MinGW/GCC but can be used with VC++ (including Express edition). WxSmith uses WxWidgets which would feel more familiar to MFC developers than Qt perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, Microsoft released [Visual Studio Community](http://www.visualstudio.com/), a new free version that has same features from Professional editon. This version includes the Resource Editor.