# Adding forms to project

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I created a project on VC++ 12 and added one form and it worked fine(using the entry point `int main(array <string^> ^args)` etc... in the **frm1.cpp** file. The problem arises when I add another form(*frm2*) to my project(I use the same code in the .cpp as frm1). It gives me

> error LNK2005: "int __clrcall sole::main(cli::array^)"
>   (?main@sole@@YMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z) already defined in
>   frm1.obj

AND

> error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found strong text

Comment: Apparently you copied the main method. You can only have one main method per application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a C++/CLI Winforms app in VS2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188757/how-do-i-create-a-c-cli-winforms-app-in-vs2012)