# OpenFileDialoug Current Thread Must Be STA before OLE calls made

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli, openfiledialog, savefiledialog, sta

Can someone explain to me what this error I'm seeing is?

Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made.

Specifically, I'm trying to open the SaveFileDialog/OpenFileDialog within C++/CLI on a form.

```
SaveFileDialog^ saveFileDialog1 = gcnew SaveFileDialog;
saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog();
    if (saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        s = saveFileDialog1->OpenFile();
        }
        s->Close();
    }
```

The error that is throwing is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.

I'm not really familiar with what this error is saying. I know just a bit about threading, but I'm not sure how threading would be an issue here. I've seen some people reference things like STAThread without providing a clear explanation as to what it does, and Microsoft's documentation makes no mention of having this exception thrown when calling SaveFileDialog/OpenFileDialog, or how to handle it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When you use OpenFileDialog then a *lot* of code gets loaded into your process.  Not just the operating system component that implements the dialog but also *shell extensions*.  Plugins that programmers write to add functionality to Windows Explorer.  They work in that dialog as well.  There are many, one you are surely familiar with is the extension that makes a .zip file look like a folder.

One thing Microsoft did when they designed the plug-in interface is to *not* force an extension to be thread-safe.  Because that is very hard to do and often a major source of bugs.  They made the promise that the thread that creates the plugin instance is *also* the thread on which any call to the plugin is made.  Thus ensuring that the plugin is always used in a thread-safe manner.

That however requires a little help from you.  You have to make a *promise* that your thread, the one that calls OpenFileDialog::Show(), observes the requirements of a single-threaded apartment.  STA for short.  You make the promise with the [STAThread] attribute on your program's Main() entrypoint.  Or if it is a thread that you created yourself then by calling Thread::SetApartmentState() before you start it.

That's just a promise however, you also have to implement what you promised.  Takes two things, you promise to never block the thread and you promise to pump a message loop.  Application::Run() in a .NET program.  The never-block promise ensures that you won't cause deadlock.  And the message loop promise says that you implement a solution to the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

This should never be a problem, it is very unclear how this got fumbled in your project.  Another implicit requirement for a dialog is that it must have an owner.  Another window on which it can be on top of.  If it doesn't have one then there are very high odds that the user never sees the dialog.  Covered by another program's window, the user can only ever find it back by accident.  When you create windows then you always also must call Application::Run() so the windows can respond to user input.  Use the [boilerplate code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034) in a C++/CLI app so this is done correctly.