# LNK 1561: No Entry Point Error?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, linker-errors, entry-point

I'm writing a simple c++ windows forms application in Visual Studio 2015, but it will no longer build as I keep getting this linker error now. The only thing is, I have a Main function to serve as my entry point that still uses all of the same default arguments it had when it was linking correctly, so I'm not sure what to do about it.

I did include an external library and had to play around with some of the directories and such, which is the only thing I could think could have happened, though I've already gone through them and made sure they are formatted correctly, no extra backslashes that might accidentally cause an escape, and nothing critical seems to have been changed.

And truthfully, that's only my best guess and I can't definitively prove that's when it stopped linking correctly anyway. Maybe somebody else has some ideas, because I haven't personally been able to find a solution that works so far. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034

Comment: I realize that there isn't much support anymore for windows forms, but this is more a quick way to prototype an idea I had before implementing it into a larger program of a different type. That said, I wasn't able to find out why the old main function stopped working, but I think it has something to do with me changing my build target to x64 so that a library I'm using will work properly with it. Ultimately, I fixed it by changing the Main function call to "int main (array<String^>^ args)" rather than "void Main (..)" It pulls up a command line in the background (agh!), but its ok for now