# An error occurs when opening MyForm.h in Visual Studio 2017 using C++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio

[Updates] 12/3/2017
Thanks for @Hans Passant .
I have edited my MyForm.h by following the instruction. However, I'm not able to open the MyForm[Design], the same error occurs. And seems like something wrong with my Linker and Entry Point? Refer to the image:
[image]
[image]
I created a C++/CLR Empty Project, and I clicked Project->Add New Item..., I selected UI under Visual C++, and chose Winform then trying to add it. However an alert pops when I added it:

> To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Designer.Interfaces.IVSMDCodeDomProvider.get_CodeDomProvider()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_Provider()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_CompileUnit()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

[image]
What should I do to solve it?
Thank you!

Comment: Build your project first.  Winforms support got unstable at VS2015, follow the guidelines in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant thanks. I looked the post, my problem occurs at second step l.

Comment: That just talks about adding the item, not about opening it.  Build first before you try to open.  Not actually sure why this is necessary. but as noted this is getting unstable.  The project templates for Winforms were removed 5 years ago, it is not getting maintained.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you! But I still can't open the Design View. I've updated my post with more details. Would you please have a look? Thank you!

Comment: Fix the build errors.  You did not follow the instructions in the linked post.  "Main" != "main", casing matters.  If you have trouble diagnosing problems like this then you should *not* be doing this, the toolchain is not exactly forgiving.  Create a C# Winforms project instead.  If you need to interop with native C++ code then create a CLR class library project.

Comment: @HansPassant Never mind, I've add `?mainCRTStartupStrArray@@$$FYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z` for my entry point, seems it can build now.