# Illegal Instruction in exe_common.inl

Tags: c++, .net, windows, visual-studio

This is about a week I am trying to solve my problem and I really need help. I hope someone will find what is wrong with my setup.

(I am french so I apologize for any English mistakes)

**CONTEXT**

I have a Visual Studio Project which has been developed from OpenFace, a free open-source library, downloaded at that address:https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace . "Developed from" because the project just uses the code of OpenFace. I precise that the project was not made by me, I checked out from a private repository.

**PROBLEM**

My project build an executable but not run, stopped by an illegal instruction at the file exe_common.inl (don't know what this file is) at the line 223, before getting into in the entry point of my programm (cout << " " << endl at the very beggining of the main() function is not executed).

Here is the guilty line:

```
__scrt_current_native_startup_state = __scrt_native_startup_state::initialized;
```

Here the stack trace at that breakpoint:

```
CamFeaturesExtractor_Affich.exe!dlib::get_global_clock(void)
CamFeaturesExtractor_Affich.exe!00007ff63493114e()
ucrtbase.dll!_initterm()
CamFeaturesExtractor_Affich.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() line 223
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
```

Here the exact message exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF63499C5B7 in CamFeaturesExtractor_Affich.exe: 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction.
```

**WHAT I TRIED**

- Change VS 2017 to 2015
- Build in Debug/Release in x64/x86
- Change Enhanced Instruction Set in Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation to AVX, AVX2, SSE, SSE2, IA32, No Set...
- Disable any optimization

That problem doesn't appear on some more recent computer (check below for my spec) so my first guess is to say that is a hardware problem. The exception is not triggered on Intel Cord Duo I5 (with same model of computer than mine). Here is my specs:

```
Edition : Windows 10 Professionel
Version : 1511
OS Version : 10586.679
Processor : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 2950M @ 2.00 GHz 2.00 GHz
RAM : 4G
System type : OS 64 bits, processeur x64
```

If the problem comes from my poor processor doesn't have the instruction, is there a workaround or I need to change my computer ?
Let me know if you need some informations I forgot to provide and thanks in advance if you try to help me...

**EDIT**

The part of disassembly where the code stop as requested:

```
00007FF6D635B5BD  mov         eax,0FFh  
00007FF6D635B5C2  jmp         __scrt_common_main_seh+167h (07FF6D635B6B3h)  

            _initterm(__xc_a, __xc_z);
00007FF6D635B5C7  lea         rdx,[__xc_z (07FF6D639ED98h)]  
00007FF6D635B5CE  lea         rcx,[__xc_a (07FF6D639EC10h)]  
00007FF6D635B5D5  call        _initterm (07FF6D635C4B0h)  

            __scrt_current_native_startup_state = __scrt_native_startup_state::initialized;
00007FF6D635B5DA  mov         dword ptr [__scrt_current_native_startup_state (07FF6D64162E0h)],2  
        }
        else
00007FF6D635B5E4  jmp         __scrt_common_main_seh+0A2h (07FF6D635B5EEh)  
        {
            has_cctor = true;
00007FF6D635B5E6  mov         sil,1  
00007FF6D635B5E9  mov         byte ptr [has_cctor],sil  
        }

        __scrt_release_startup_lock(is_nested);
00007FF6D635B5EE  mov         cl,bl  
00007FF6D635B5F0  call        __scrt_release_startup_lock (07FF6D635B368h)
```

Note that exe_common.inl, as said in comment, is a Read-Only Visual Studio file located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\crt\src\vcruntime\exe_common.inl. I made a gist if you want to see it: https://gist.github.com/AlEmerich/281994ebbcde7d3bac88f21a85de96e2

**LAST EDIT:**
I don't know if it is the right way to do but I let know the audience that I give up on that problem by trying to change my computer. I have now a more recent hardware and it throws any errors. Thanks anyway for your help !

Comment: The guilty line has C++ syntax and comes from dlib, an external, unmanaged library. You will hardly get this solved under the C# tag.

Comment: *"stopped by an illegal instruction at the file exe_common.inl (don't know what this file is)"* Well, I don't know what the file is, either. I did a search in [the repository for the project you say you're using](https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace), and it doesn't have a file with this name. So this file is either something you've created, or from some other project you're using and forgot to mention. It is very important. In order to debug this, we need to either see this file or see the disassembly. Visual Studio should show you both after it breaks on the illegal instruction.

Comment: But if you're building targeting x86 and you've changed the instruction set to IA32 (`/arch:IA32`), then you should ***not*** be getting any instructions generated that require a modern processor to execute. The code that gets generated with these options will run on processors as old as the 386. So either you aren't setting the options correctly (maybe you're setting them for the wrong project?), or this `exe_common.inl` file is using inline assembly (or intrinsics) to force a particular instruction to be emitted. Again, we need to see the file.

Comment: exe_common.inl is VS files located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\crt\src\vcruntime\exe_common.inl.
It shows me the disassembly, I edit my post with it. Thank you by the way for reading me

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize this was a CRT file. Thanks for posting it. I don't see anything suspicious about this file. It certainly isn't using any inline assembly or forcing any instructions that might be invalid on your system. Everything in the disassembly you've posted looks perfectly safe (except the `sil` register, which only exists in x64, but you said you have a 64-bit OS). Without having a [mcve] actually loaded into a debugger, it's hard for me to trace what the problem is. It seems unlikely there's a show-stopper bug in the CRT, so do go back and check *all* your project settings.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your processor or the code snippet you copy/pasted from the CRT source.  The most common reason for this exception is a corrupted stack with the return address modified, causing the program to jump to an arbitrary address.  The price you pay for using a C or C++ library.  A little birdy tells me that you are using a Winforms project written in C++/CLI, the kind of scenario that got very brittle at VS2015.  Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034) to see configuration hints.

Comment: Code Gray - I will try to make one as soon as possible.
Hans Passant - I'll take a hint on that, thank for the link.

Answer (score 1):

For me, remove `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` from Release Mode and try to build in Release Mode.
It should contain some errors, fix them and than it should be fine.