# Solve "LINK : fatal error LNK1561: the entry point must be defined"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I am working with Visual Studio Ultimate 2012.

If I run the code from Visual Studio it works properly. But if I take the ".exe" file that it generates at the Debug file it doesn't in another computer.
That is why I change the menu from "Debug" to "Release", but then it doesn't compile and shows the message: "LINK : fatal error LNK1561: the entry point must be defined"

What do I have to change at the configuration to create a ".exe" that works in any computer?

I have a main defined in the project as `void main(array<String^>^ arg)`

Comment: The Windows Forms project templates were removed in VS2012.  That got lots of programmers in trouble, particularly the ones that don't tag their question correctly and don't tell us what they did to keep their project compiling.  Focus on making the same setting changes you made in the Debug build.   Use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034) as a guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the signature of the `main` function is wrong. The expected signature for the EntryPoint `main` function should have `int` return type in VS2012.

Please try changing signature of function to:

`int main(array<String^>^ arg)`

This may resolve your problem.