# Visual C++ CLR designer is always showing 0x8000000A error in the second run of the project and editing design

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm trying to make a great GUI for my csgo cheat. I decided to use C++/CLR. 
Firstly I create empty project then, I change in a properties entrypoint and the subsystem and I add this code to the cpp file:

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;`

using namespace System::Windows::Forms;`

[STAThreadAttribute]
void Main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
 Application::EnableVisualStyles();
 Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
 SmallPackofCheats::MyForm mainForm;
 Application::Run(%mainForm);
}
```

Then I save it and I restart visual studio. I run visual studio and I design menu. Designer works. After ended work I save everything and I close Visual Studio. Every next run of the Visual Studio and after opening my project I have this problem:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0OHy.png)

How to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This VS feature is not actively being maintained anymore since the C++ Winforms templates were removed in VS2012.  Stuff keeps falling off with each release.  This particular issue is not a huge problem, rebuilding the project was always enough in my experience.  More about this in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034).

Comment: Thank you very much you've solved my problem every thing works after cleaning and rebulding project.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar problem recently and the other suggested solutions did not help.  This method, however, did work:

1. Window -> Close all Documents (or at least ensure that every designer window is closed)
2. Close VS and restart it (important!)
3. Reopen the solution
4. Build -> Rebuild Solution

Now you should be able to open the designer.

Comment: this seems to fix my issue as well. i suspect it has to do with something getting cached before the linker is set

Answer (score 0):

After lots of struggles I came up with easy workaround that always fix the issue:
Close VS, then erase the hidden directory '.vs' and the 'x64' or 'x32' - then open VS and it should open the designer without problem.