# Tracing all DLL loading and initializations in C++/CLI

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, c++-cli

I have a complex C++/CLI application with numerous modules (a few dozens), some managed some unmanaged. Recently we switched from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015. It's working on some computers but not on others.

When the program isn't working, it crashes even before the first line of main. It reports an Access Violation Exception in `_onexit` . When ignoring some of the exceptions and assertions I see that a `<Module>` threw a `TypeInitializationException` .

Problem is - I have no idea which one. I can see when DLLs are loaded in the Output window. The last DLL to load is `System.dll` - surely my bug is not there. So I need a way to trace static variable initialization in managed DLLs so I can figure out which DLL is problematic, then I can track down the problematic initialization.

How can I do that?

Comment: Focus less on the question "What module?" and more on the question "What type didn't load?"  The `TypeInitializationException` should have [that information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception.typename.aspx) in its details.  You should also have a stack trace.

Comment: Probably you have a static class or a static member which fails on main entry. It can be a logger or a singleton object. Etc.

Comment: @BenVoigt, unfortunately the debugger doesn't catch the exception, as it happens *after* the GPF, so I can't really say which type it is at an "unknown" module. I suspect it's `<Module>` which is a C++/CLI type containing all of a modules global variables and functions. So I need to trace the initializations.

Comment: @Y.Doktur of course this is the problem, I just don't know which one it is out of all the practically hundreds of static variables in the code. And searching for it by disabling each one (even in a binary search fashion) will take weeks.

Comment: Nothing should stop the debugger from catching an unhandled exception.  Only explanation I can think of is that you don't have the debugger actually attached to your process.  Have you enabled Mixed-mode debugger (both native and managed)?  Both kinds of debugger will print `OutputDebugString` messages, but only the correct debugger will break when the exception occurs....  Beyond that, you should be debugging and fixing the first exception you run into.  After the program's state is corrupted, the debugger is still expected to work but what you see won't be very meaningful.

Comment: The debugger is in mixed mode. The first exception happens in _onexit, after everything has happened already. This is due to some heap corruption I suspect.

Comment: Do you debug with Visual Studio? For edge cases, it sometimes doesn't really work well IMHO. For these cases I use WinDbg (the new one in preview is quite nice).

Comment: This rings a bell, I'd have to see the stack trace to positively identify it.   The CRT rewrite in VS2015 suffers from static initialization order fiasco problems.  Most typically triggered in a C++/CLI app that targets System::Windows::Forms, it is the module initializer that keels over.  Survival guide [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034), the hack discovered by @pianoslum (overriding the entrypoint) is the one you probably want.

Comment: Did fuslogvw actually made the job? I got the bounty but I'm not convinced. I would rather delete the answer then leaving a wrong one.

Answer (score 3):

Well, i feel a little stupid, but in a problem while loading with a type load exception I used [fuslogvw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer).

I think it should give you the order of dll bindings and therefore a first impression.