# What is array<String^>^ arg? And why do we pass it to main()?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

What is `array<String ^> ^arg` and why do we pass it to `main()` function when creating a winform application?

Comment: Is your question about what the type means, or what kinds of values the main function might receive?

Comment: @hvd yes exactly

Comment: To "do you mean A or B?", useful answers are "A" or "B", not "yes"...

Comment: That is the signature for the entrypoint of a .NET managed program.  Still writing [winforms] programs in C++/CLI is getting to be a dangerously lost art, find survival tips in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034).  And do read the FM, no hope to pull it off when you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an array of strings, each representing one of the arguments sent to your program when it was launched.