# Visual C++ application uses Windows 7 Basic style at run time

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c++-cli

In the form designer, the form appears to use the windows aero style but when ran, all controls use the windows 7 basic style. The desktop is currently set to use windows aero.

In Designer:

[image: Designer Image]

At Run Time:

[image: At Run Time Image]

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: The designer always uses visual styles because VS itself enables it.  At runtime your code decides the theme, presumably you forgot to call Application::EnableVisualStyles() in your Main function.  These kind of mistakes are quite common since they removed the project template, a survival guide [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034).

Answer (score 0):

In the properties window of the elements there is a "Style" category that you can configure.

Comment: None of the properties seem to solve this issue. It is appearing in the designer how I want it to look but changes when ran.  My only thought as of now is that it is a windows setting affecting this but windows aero is enabled on the desktop