# Missing View Design in Visual C++ (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I can't open View Design in VS 2017, it's just missing.
It doesn't show any desinger in the open methods.

[image]

Neither in the other pop-up window..

[image]

Comment: Pieces keep falling off, starting 7 years ago with the removal of the Winforms project templates.  The only remaining way to open the designer is to double-click the file.  Do take this as a hint that the future [looks bleak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is MFC project, it has a '.rc' file. Double click this file will lead you to dialog or view designer. Other wise these is NO any view design. The second picture you mentioned can only navigate you to '.cpp' file of an '.h' file.