# Windows Form designer (resx file) is not created when adding a new Form to the project

Tags: .net, clr, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2019

I recently started to work with Visual Studio 2019 (2015 had no problems like this one). I somehow created a primary Windows Form without any bugs. But after I tried to create another Windows Form in the same project (Sol Explorer->Add->New Item->CLR->Windows Form), the header and the cpp file were created, but resx file was not. So the Windows Form designer is missing. It also cannot be accessed from the Solution Explorer menu ('View Designer' is missing).

How to fix the problem? I couldn't find a solution, but some articles mention missing tags in Visual Studio.

Comment: By design.  Support for Windows Forms in C++/CLI diminishes with every release.  VS2008 was the last version that supported it well, VS2012 is bearable if you need to target .NET 4.  From there is all down hill.  "Don't do it" is the only good advice, you'll have to stick with an old VS version if that is hard to do.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That worked for me after several attempts:

1. Clean & rebuild solution
2. Create a new Form
3. Repeat step 1
4. Relaunch VS

Designer and .resx file appeared from nowhere