# Create single form application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I need to create very basic single form application in my MS Visual Studio 2019, Visual c++. I prefer to design this form in designer. I create new application in my Visual C++ by selecting new `Windows Desktop Application`. As result I got main form that I can't design in designer. I prefer to have dialog style based form similar to `About` form that I can edit in designer as main form. How to achieve that?

Comment: If you're comfortable using MFC, then create a new MFC Application and select "Dialog Based."

Comment: Pieces keep falling off the support for C++ Winforms projects.  The workaround is to build the project first before trying to open the form in the designer.  Survival guide [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188757/how-do-i-create-a-c-cli-winforms-app-in-vs2012/15190400#15190400).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you could try to use MFC to create a form based on dialog style

First of all, you should installed with the Desktop development with C++ workload and the optional Visual C++ MFC for x86 and x64 component.

And then you could create a form based on dialog style.

1,Use the MFC Application Wizard to create a new MFC application. To run the wizard, from the File menu select New, and then select Project. The New Project dialog box will be displayed.

2,In the New Project dialog box, expand the Visual C++ node in the Project types pane and select MFC. Then, in the Templates pane, select MFC Application. Type a name for the project, and click OK.

[image]

3,On the Application Type pane,under Application type select Dialog based. click finish, and you have created a form based on dialog style.

[image]

For more details I suggest you could refer to the Doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/creating-an-mfc-application?view=vs-2019