# Fatal error c1001 when trying to make a GUI program in C++ CLR using .NET core in MSVS Enterprise 2019 16.4.6

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I tried to make a C++ GUI program, i started with an empty project, and then add source file which is UI->windows form, and made a main function to call it. But when i tried to run it, it always shows this error

> C1001 An internal error has occurred in the compiler

I also set the linker->system->subsystem into windows(/subsystem:windows)
and set entry point to my main function.
this is my main cpp file.

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace Project1;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Windows;

int main()
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Project1::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(% form);
}
```

this is my header file(automaticaly created by VS)

```
#pragma once

namespace Project1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(1089, 508);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    };
}
```

it has over 2k warning, i can't possibly put it all here

Comment: Isn't it normally `WinMain` for gui applications?

Comment: excuse me, can you explain more about WinMain. I'm really new at this. it's a college assignment

Comment: The project is not configured correctly.  Do not start with a .NETCore template.  Survival guide [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034).

Comment: i started with empty profect

Comment: For more details about the steps of how to create C++ Windows Forms application,I suggest you could refer to the link:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a9529502-6304-4aa6-90ee-0757ab258d87/create-c-windows-forms-application-in-visual-studio-2017?forum=winforms