# C++/CLI V.S error " ClassLibrary.dll isn't a valid win32 application" . Changing startup item

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to creat "UserControl" then add it to "MainForm" in C++/CLI. But i found only one solution to add "UserControl" to "MainForm" via creating project as a Class Library.dll ...
But in this case I can't Target Startup Item to Main form to Build .exe and V.S gives an error normally when trying to build "ClassLibrary" . Any Solution for it? ....[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdOYd.png)

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034) is supposed to scare you away from pursuing this.

Comment: This is another solution for creating Form but i need solution to add userControl to mainForm

Comment: We found the same thread on Q&A, and I suggest you could refer this thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/352404/ccli-vs-error-34-classlibrarydll-isn39t-a-valid-wi.html