# Visual Studio 2022 CLR Empty Project (.NET Framework) entry point is not working, even after being set

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, visual-studio-2022, clr, program-entry-point

I am trying to run a Windows Form in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022. When I attempt to run the solution I get the following error: "LNK1561 entry point must be defined", which links to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev17.query?appId=Dev17IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(LNK1561);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2)&rd=true).

I have followed every step of [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/zv8DkkhBNR0?feature=shared), and have added the entry point to the linker via Project properties (shown in the screenshots below), but the error persists.

Screenshots:
[image: compiler with error]

[image: project properties subsystem]

[image: project properties entry point]

Here is the code for MainForm.cpp:

```
#include "MainForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
void main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    EyeDropperUI::MainForm form;
    Application::Run(% form);
}
```

and MainForm.h:

```
#pragma once

namespace EyeDropperUI {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MainForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MainForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MainForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MainForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->components = gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container();
            this->Size = System::Drawing::Size(300,300);
            this->Text = L"MainForm";
            this->Padding = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(0);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        }
#pragma endregion
    };
}
```

I am new to Visual Studio so I'm not sure where to go from here, I have tried changing the entry point name in both the code and Project Properties, but from my understanding this should be working.

I cannot find a stackoverflow post that contains the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you all for your time. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190400/17034

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you modified is not active page:

[image]

[image]